# gdm3 login loop, lightdm works in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: login, 20.04, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

A lot of people seem to have this issue, and many people have been able to fix it, but I have used *every fix* (besides reinstalling Ubuntu or creating a new user and moving stuff over) and have not been able to fix it.

When gdm3 is enabled, I get a login loop. Nothing special about it, just a normal type in my password, press Enter, get a quick black screen, and get looped back to login. I'm currently using lightdm and I get no login loop. I type in my password and press Enter and it works perfectly.

What I hate about using it though, is that it asks for authentication for almost *everything*. Want to mount a drive? Want to shut down the computer? Authentication dialog, authentication dialog. This is why I want to get gdm3 back.

Fixes I've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling gdm3, lightdm, and ubuntu-desktop. (tried fglrx, but I don't have it apparently)
- Set .Xauthority permissions
- Checked that .bashrc is default (compared my the one in my home folder with the one in /etc/skel/)
- Checking that auto-login is disabled

Results of `ps -ef | grep polk` and `dpkg -l | grep polk` :

[image]

Honestly I can't remember any more fixes I've done, but I know I've tried almost every fix out there besides reinstalling Ubuntu or creating a new user and moving stuff over. Reinstalling is my last resort, so does anyone have anything I could try to fix this? I'm ready to try almost anything at this point...

**Edit:**

After searching through the logs, I found this line:

```
Error registering session with GDM: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.DisplayManager was not provided by any .service files
```

I think this is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem! Around the time it started happening, I followed a tutorial for a hotfix for Chrome Remote Desktop. After searching through `/var/log/syslog`, I found errors with Chrome Remote Desktop. All I had to do, was go into a TTY (`Ctrl+Alt+F3`), sign in, and run:

```
sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot, I signed in successfully, and no authentication dialogs have popped up!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by removing long environment variables from my .bashrc. My `LS_COLORS` variable was over 9000 characters long as it was generated using `dircolors`. For some reason this was causing gdm3 to crash. In /var/log/syslog I was getting the error:

```
gnome-session-b[16553]: segfault at ... error 6 in libpcre.so.3.13.3 ...
```

It must be a bug in libpcre.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to log in successfully.

I found [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/fix-cant-login-after-logout-with-gnome.html)

```
killall -9 -u $USER
```

Writing to'/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default' in the article works on logout.
However, restarting does not work.

I think that the cause is not to log out correctly, but I do not know the correct action.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get a login loop after trying this...